# Read data from UART - GPS Parsing

Tags: c, gps, avr, uart

I have a program that works only if it is GPS enabled.
In a while (1) still call this function.

```
gps_get_nmea(nmea_in, sizeof(nmea_in));
```

This function to retrieve data from the UART from '$' to '\n'

Gps_get_nmea function is here:

```
void gps_get_nmea(char* buf, uint8_t bufSize){
char inChar;
uint8_t curSize = 0;

do {
    inChar = gps_get_char();
} while(inChar != '$');

while( inChar != '\n' && curSize < bufSize - 2) {
    *buf++ = inChar;
    curSize++;
    inChar = gps_get_char();
}

*buf++ = '\n';
*buf = '\0';
}
```

And function gps_get_char() here:

```
char gps_get_char(){
unsigned int in = 0;
do {
    in = uart1_getc();
} while((in & UART_NO_DATA) || (in & UART_BUFFER_OVERFLOW));

return((char) in);
}
```

**If the GPS is turned off, the entire program is stopped.
The problem is in those loops 'DO WHILE'**

But I do not know how to remove this problem.

So how do I do to get out UART data beginning with '$' and ending with '\ n' ???

[To communicate with the UART using the library from Peter Fleury.](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/peterfleury/uartlibrary.zip)

Comment: The more useful way to get data from a UART is to use interrupts. Create an ISR that buffers characters as it gets them, then your main loop can check for characters in the buffer rather than polling for them at the port. There's plenty of sample AVR code for this.

Comment: ...which is what OP's final link to Peter Fleury contains.

Comment: You are aware that the '$' and '\n' is sent from the GPS? If the GPS is turned off, you will not get any '$' or '\n' from the UART. Instead you will need to consider things like non blocking IO and handle things like short reads as a result of non blocking IO.

Comment: Yes. I had to add a condition to the ISR interrupt from the UART.  A program now works correctly.